# Failed to find device node for boot cpu missing boot CPU MPIDR, not enabling secondaries

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, u-boot, device-tree

we are trying to boot Arm64/Aarch64 Linux kernel(5.9) using device tree.
In device tree we add the below nodes:

1.CPUs
2.Memory
3.Serial
4.Interrupt-controller (GIC)
5.Timer

Our implementation : Bootloader -> Linuxkernel

We used this CPUs node in devicetree

```
cpus {
    #size-cells = <0x00>;
    #address-cells = <0x01>;

    cpu@0 {
        reg = <0x00>;
        compatible = "arm,armv8";
        device_type = "cpu";
        enable-method = "psci";
        next-level-cache = <&xgene_L2_0>;
    };

    cpu@1 {
        reg = <0x01>;
        compatible = "arm,armv8";
        device_type = "cpu";
        enable-method = "psci";
        next-level-cache = <&xgene_L2_0>;
    };

    xgene_L2_0: l2-cache-0 {
        compatible = "cache";
        cache-level = <2>;
        cache-unified;
    };
};
```

facing the below warning,

> Failed to find device node for boot cpu

> missing boot CPU MPIDR, not enabling secondaries

any views and ideas to resolve this ...... ????

Comment: Is there a `Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xXX00YYYYYY [0xZZZZZZZZ]` message in the kernel log?

Comment: Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000002a00 [0xc00fac30]
Linux version 5.9.0 (user1@user-OptiPlex-5000) (aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #1 SMP Thu Oct 19 10:38:36 IST 2023
Machine model: inspur,mitchell-mb
earlycon: pl11 at MMIO 0x0000400000c00000 (options '')

Comment: So I guess the node for the boot CPU should be something like: `cpu@2a00 {` `reg = <0x2a00>;` … `};` I don't know the reg value for the other CPU.

Comment: Thanks Ian Abbott ... now it is worked